# MySQL REPLACE Table Values using Identical Staging table Trigger Without Defining Columns

Tags: mysql

Within a MySQL 8 database I have two identical tables in different schemas with one being used as a staging table for its equivalent production table. The tables contain 200+ columns with more to be added in the future, making explicitly defining values for column names difficult.

I need to INSERT or UPDATE values in the production table with those in the staging table using an AFTER INSERT trigger, where all values of a row within the production table are replaced upon the existence of a duplicate PRIMARY KEY. Note that the production table has its PRIMARY KEY defined.

After this, I should delete all rows from the staging table.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER stage.my_table_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO prod.my_table
        SELECT * FROM new;
    DELETE FROM stage.my_table
END
```

Comment: What is "SELECT * FROM new;" ?

Comment: @jaczes "SELECT * FROM new;" is me trying to extract all columns from the row inserted into the staging table (so these an then be inserted into the production table). That particular statement will not run as the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: It's first time when I see such syntax ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why are You doing so, but why arent you doing something like:

```
REPLACE INTO prod.my_table
SELECT * FROM stage.my_table; 
DELETE FROM stage.my_table;
```

Comment: It turns out you cant alter a table inside within its own trigger, so I had to remove the section:
`DELETE FROM stage.my_table;`
However, I now get the error: 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'.

Answer (score 0):

You cant alter a table within its own contained trigger. Additionally, using a trigger will execute all SQL statements once per row (inefficient in this case). Therefore, a procedure is instead used to perform the required functions, using the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE stage.load_data()
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO prod.my_table
    SELECT * FROM stage.my_table; 
    DELETE FROM stage.my_table;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```